# Easiest way to transfer data to frontend using JSP

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I have faced a big problem. I'm using Spring MVC and JSP for creating a static web application. Unfortunatelly I have to use Javascript and passing values to the model to then read it in JS function seems like horrible idea. What is the easiest way to pass data to JSP so then I can use it in Javascript function?

Comment: Create a model in JSP and then load it using javascript, there's no need to use Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data as js objects. That is the simple and powerful way. Please refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Before that, Expose your beans to JSP. for e-g you have MyBean, spring xml is to be changed as below

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
    <list>
      <value>MyBean</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you specify how to do that? Create controller with @ResponseBody?